# Predicting the nth state of cellular automata

Tags: cellular-automata

Does anybody know if it is is possible to predict the nth state of cellular automata using a function?
I think it might be possible to do on one dimensional automata using differential equations, but I was wondering if there is a formal method out there already.
Thanks

Comment: This question looks more suitable for *Computer Science StackExchange*. The question also looks too broad; HashLife is one way to predict, but in general, nope, you cannot predict the nth state of a general cellular automata.

Comment: Well I did a search, and I found most of the cellular automata questions here.

Comment: I second the suggestion of asking on [cs.se]. In any case, it depends very much on the automaton. For some automata predicting any future state is trivial; for others it can be provably hard in a quantifiable sense, e.g. because the automaton can emulate arbitrary computation.